# When launching icCube report how can I get the user name

Tags: iccube-reporting

in ic3Report.html file, is it possible to get the user name in the callback function ?

```
var options = {
        root: "ic3-report/app/",
        rootLocal: "ic3-report/app-local/",
        rootVersion: "_IC3_ROOT_VERSION_",
        callback: function () {
            $('#intro').remove();
            window.ic3application = ic3.startReport(
                    {
                        <!-- ic3-start-report-options (DO NOT REMOVE - USED TO GENERATE FILES) -->
                    });
           // get user name here !
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to gather current user information you should setup GVI configuration. It could be done with appropriate method:

```
var options = {
    root: "ic3-report/app/",
    rootLocal: "ic3-report/app-local/",
    rootVersion: "_IC3_ROOT_VERSION_",
    callback: function () {
        $('#intro').remove();
        var ic3reporting = new ic3.Reporting(
                    {
                        noticesLevel: ic3.NoticeLevel.INFO,
                        dsSettings: {
                            url: GVI_URL
                        }
                    });
        ic3reporting.setupGVIConfiguration(function () {
            var userName = ic3reporting.userName();
        })
    }
};
```

After that user information will be available inside context. See code above for details.

### Update

A more robust solution is adding the code to the local files that are not overwritten with a new version of the reporting. You can use **ic3bootstrapLocal** function in **Admin > Common JS** configuration.

```
function ic3bootstrapLocal(options) {  
   var ic3reporting = new ic3.Reporting({
       noticesLevel: ic3.NoticeLevel.INFO,
    });

   ic3reporting.setupGVIConfiguration(function(){
      ic3reporting.userName()
      options.callback && options.callback();     
   });        
}
```